# MySQL find_in_set with multiple search string

Tags: sql, mysql, search

I find that **find_in_set** only search by a single string :-

```
find_in_set('a', 'a,b,c,d')
```

In the above example, 'a' is the only string used for search.

Is there any way to use find_in_set kind of functionality and search by multiple strings, like :-

```
find_in_set('a,b,c', 'a,b,c,d')
```

In the above example, I want to search by three strings 'a,b,c'.

One way I see is using **OR**

```
find_in_set('a', 'a,b,c,d') OR find_in_set('b', 'a,b,c,d') OR find_in_set('b', 'a,b,c,d')
```

Is there any other way than this?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

there is no native function to do it, but you can achieve your aim using following trick

```
WHERE CONCAT(",", `setcolumn`, ",") REGEXP ",(val1|val2|val3),"
```

Comment: And for rails it works as Model.where('CONCAT(",", `setcolumn`, ",") REGEXP ?', [val1,val2,val3].join('|'))

Comment: What if my val1|val2|val3 are not in order as the DB entries.

Comment: Amazing answer! - saves me seconds on my query replacing the find_in_set

You can eve do this for 2 tables T1 and T2:

.... where CONCAT(",", T1.setcolumn, ",") REGEXP CONCAT(",(", REPLACE(T2.setcolumn, ',', '|'), "),")

Comment: Hi, this is working in Mysql. But in PHP i added same. its throwing error for  "syntax error, unexpected ',' in Line"

Comment: @AbijithAjayan I've solved same problem with adding **Allow User Variables=true** in the connection string

Comment: This works great, saved me from stucking in Waiting for table lock and Copying to tmp table freezes...Though, i use it at product filtering and OR is not so good for "filtering"..Any idea how i could use the optimisation for "AND"..before i was using JOIN for each and every Option selected, which resulted in 5-7 different JOINs in same table for different FIND_IN_SET (optionid, "in optionids")...

Comment: Nice solution, but I found it to be significantly slower than concatenating FIND_IN_SET with OR

Answer (score 16):

The MySQL function [`find_in_set()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) can search only for one string in a set of strings.

The first argument is a string, so there is no way to make it parse your comma separated string into strings (you can't use commas in SET elements at all!). The second argument is a SET, which in turn is represented by a comma separated string hence your wish to `find_in_set('a,b,c', 'a,b,c,d')` which works fine, but it surely can't find a string `'a,b,c'` in any SET by definition - it contains commas.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think The only solution for my problem will be using OR and finset. Like "find_in_set('a', 'a,b,c,d') OR find_in_set('b', 'a,b,c,d') OR find_in_set('b', 'a,b,c,d')".

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this custom function

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, ''); 

DELIMITER $$
    CREATE FUNCTION `FIND_SET_EQUALS`(`s1` VARCHAR(200), `s2`  VARCHAR(200)) 
    RETURNS TINYINT(1)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    BEGIN
          DECLARE a INT Default 0 ;
            DECLARE isEquals TINYINT(1) Default 0 ;
          DECLARE str VARCHAR(255);
          IF s1 IS NOT NULL AND s2 IS NOT NULL THEN
             simple_loop: LOOP
                 SET a=a+1;
                 SET str= SPLIT_STR(s2,",",a);
                 IF str='' THEN
                    LEAVE simple_loop;
                 END IF;
                 #Do  check is in set
                 IF FIND_IN_SET(str, s1)=0 THEN
                    SET isEquals=0;
                     LEAVE simple_loop;
                 END IF;
                 SET isEquals=1;
            END LOOP simple_loop;
          END IF;
        RETURN isEquals;
    END;
    $$
    DELIMITER ;

SELECT FIND_SET_EQUALS('a,c,b', 'a,b,c')- 1
SELECT FIND_SET_EQUALS('a,c', 'a,b,c')- 0
SELECT FIND_SET_EQUALS(null, 'a,b,c')- 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I'm surprised no one ever mentioned this here.
In a nutshell, If you know the order of your members, then just query in a single bitwise operation.

```
SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE (example_set & mbits) = mbits;
```

Explanation:

If we had a set that has members in this order: "HTML", "CSS", "PHP", "JS"... etc.
That's how they're interpreted in MySQL:

```
"HTML" = 0001 = 1
"CSS"  = 0010 = 2
"PHP"  = 0100 = 4
"JS"   = 1000 = 16
```

So for example, if you want to query all rows that have "HTML" and "CSS" in their sets, then you'll write

```
SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE (example_set & 3) = 3;
```

Because `0011` is `3` which is both `0001` *`"HTML"`* and `0010` *`"CSS"`*.

Your sets can still be queried using the other methods like REGEXP , LIKE, FIND_IN_SET(), and so on. Use whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Amazing answer by @Pavel Perminov! - And also nice comment by @doru for dynamically check..

**From there what I have made for PHP code  `CONCAT(',','" . $country_lang_id . "', ',') REGEXP CONCAT(',(', REPLACE(YourColumnName, ',', '|'), '),')` this below query may be useful for someone who is looking for ready code for PHP.**

```
$country_lang_id = "1,2";

$sql = "select a.* from tablename a where CONCAT(',','" . $country_lang_id . "', ',') REGEXP CONCAT(',(', REPLACE(a.country_lang_id, ',', '|'), '),') ";
```

Answer (score -4):

You can also use the like command for instance:

```
where setcolumn like '%a,b%'
```

or

```
where 'a,b,c,d' like '%b,c%'
```

which might work in some situations.

Comment: how can you use [where 'a,b,c,d' like '%b,c%']

it may be 'c,b' also.
So I think it's not the good solution!

Answer (score -10):

you can use in to find match values from two values

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE  myvals in (a,b,c,d)
```

Comment: IN clause does not take a variable. It uses the column http://www.w3resource.com/sql/in-operator/sql-in-operator.php