# Mysql select query to get FIND_IN_SET

Tags: mysql

The following query works good.

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');
// output -> 2
```

I need to fetch the record having multiple options. Just for an example,

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b,c','a,b,c,d');
// output -> ??????????
```

Please how do i get the record with multiple selection option "b,c" in "a,b,c,d".

Comment: Do you want TRUE when b AND c, or TRUE when b OR c? what do you want as a result for b,d ?

Comment: what output do you want to get in second example?

Answer (score 0):

mysql function `find_in_set` can search only for one string in a set of strings.

the second its not a string in set of  strings

take a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015403/mysql-find-in-set-with-multiple-search-string)

edit:

to change the mode

This can be done in two ways...

1- Open your "my.ini" file within the MySQL installation directory, and look for the text "sql-mode".

Find:

Code:

## Set the SQL mode to strict sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

Replace with:

Code:

## Set the SQL mode to strict sql-mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

Or

2- You can run an SQL query within your database management tool, such as phpMyAdmin:

Code:

```
 SET @@global.sql_mode= '';
```

Comment: Why don't you properly flag the question as duplicate since you found one?