# trouble returning both partial and exact matches

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
product_id    attribute_id
2             7,8
1             2,7
3             7
```

I also have a variable called `$search_ids` which contains values to search for.

If `$search_ids` has a value of `7` , I want it to return all 3 rows, but if it has a value of `2,7` or `7,8` I then want to return that row only.

I tried the following where `$search_ids` has a value of 7, but this doesn't return the second row! And if I change the row's value from `2,7` to `7,2` then it returns that row also!

So right now the following query:

```
$q = "SELECT product_id FROM product_attributes 
    WHERE attribute_id IN ('$search_ids')
    OR attribute_id IN ($search_ids)
```

returns

```
2
3
```

instead of

```
2
1
3
```

Comment: what is `product_attributes` a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: product_attributes is a table, attribute_ids is varchar, yes.

Comment: you should consider redesigning your table. You could use `WHERE attribute_id LIKE '%$search_ids%'` but that will not work when you have bigger numbers like `10` which would be returned when you search for `0` or `1`.

Comment: I know this isn't best practice but having a separate row for each attribute_id doesn't work for me, there is no way for me to filter it the way I want that way. This is perfect, but I need it to fix the bug I have.

Comment: Try this[This may help you a little...]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015403/mysql-find-in-set-with-multiple-search-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
$search_ids = '2,7'; //dummy data

$q = '';
$ids = explode(',', $search_ids);
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $q .= (strlen($q) == 0)?'':' AND';
    $q .= ' FIND_IN_SET(\''.$id.'\', attribute_id) > 0';
}

$q = 'SELECT product_id FROM product_attributes WHERE' . $q;
```

Comment: Now that's some pro stuff! Seems to be working, but I will need to test it a bit more, because before I thought Tanvir's asnwer worked but you spotted the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$q = "SELECT product_id FROM product_attributes 
      WHERE attribute_id REGEXP '(^|,)($search_ids)(,|$)'";
```

This will match on rows where `product_id` matches `$search_ids` if it is exactly a match, at the start of a comma separated list, in the middle of a comma separated list, or at the end of a comma separated list.

Comment: Does this work for `$search_ids = '2,7'` and one row has `attribute_id  '2,6,7'` ?

Comment: No it does not. A pure SQL solution for splitting and searching is more difficult and not as simple as this. But your PHP solution for building the query should work nicely.

Comment: kcsoft is right, it should work for `2,6,7` as well.