# Return row if different multiple id matches with different column

Tags: php, mysql

I have single table name as job_post.Now int this table city stored with the multiple city id and skill stored with the multiple skill id as show in below table.

[image]

I want to search using multiple skill id like 1,2 and multiple city id in this table.

I have tried query like this :

```
select * from job_post where FIND_IN_SET(city, '1,3') or FIND_IN_SET(skill, '1,3')
```

So, I got one result which have city 1 but I want both row instead of it if it matches single id from skill or city column.

So what query should I have to write?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL find\_in\_set with multiple search string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015403/mysql-find-in-set-with-multiple-search-string)

Comment: I want to return both row if you find in skill column as **1,3** and city column as **1,3**.Because **3** id is in skill column and **1** id is in city column.

Answer (score 0):

This is a needlessly complicated query, you really should use foreign keys and additional tables to set this up
[image]

But if you want to keep the same schema you can use a hack. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015403/mysql-find-in-set-with-multiple-search-string) for some examples. I use the following to implement it

```
Create Table job_post (
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50),
  skill VARCHAR(50),
  city VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO job_post (name,skill,city) 
  VALUES ('job1','2,3','1,2'),
  ('job2','2,3,12,13','1');   

SELECT * FROM job_post WHERE CONCAT(',', skill, ',') REGEXP ',(1|3),'
  OR CONCAT(',', city, ',') REGEXP ',(1|3),';
```

So if you're executing these from php, you just need to change the regex to include as many ids as you want. The above query returns both rows.

This query

```
SELECT * FROM job_post WHERE CONCAT(',', skill, ',') REGEXP ',(1),' OR CONCAT(',', city, ',') REGEXP ',(2|3),';
```

Only returns job1. You can play with the example [here](http://www.sqlize.com/j7R9iQrjyK)