# search on multiple column with multiple value in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
select * from vis_provider where
    FIND_IN_SET(('German'),CONCAT(
                DoctarLanguage1,',',
                DoctarLanguage2,',',
                DoctarLanguage3,',',
                DoctarLanguage4,',',
                DoctarLanguage5,',',
                DoctarLanguage6))
```

this Mysql query is working 
I want something like this

```
select * from vis_provider where
    FIND_IN_SET(('German','French'),CONCAT(
                DoctarLanguage1,',',
                DoctarLanguage2,',',
                DoctarLanguage3,',',
                DoctarLanguage4,',',
                DoctarLanguage5,',',
                DoctarLanguage6));
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having?  Also please include the table structure.

Comment: this has already been solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015403/mysql-find-in-set-with-multiple-search-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL find\_in\_set with multiple search string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015403/mysql-find-in-set-with-multiple-search-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from vis_provider 
where  FIND_IN_SET( 'German' , CONCAT( ... ) )
   OR  FIND_IN_SET( 'French' , CONCAT( ... ) )
```

Comment: I am doing this:- 
select * from vis_provider where
    
 
   (DoctarLanguage1 in('Spanish','German'))
  or
  (DoctarLanguage2 in('Spanish','German'))
  or
  (DoctarLanguage3 in('Spanish','German'))
  or
  (DoctarLanguage4 in('Spanish','German'))
  or
  (DoctarLanguage5 in('Spanish','German'))
  or
  (DoctarLanguage6 in('Spanish','German'))     can We have diffrent ways to write that code;