# REGEXP query exception in doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I'm trying `REGEXP` in Doctrine for such condition `WHERE CONCAT(",", setcolumn, ",") REGEXP ",(val1|val2|val3),"` found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26195280/1179841. I have added this in `config.yml`

```
orm:
    dql:
      string_functions:
        regexp: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Regexp
```

However I still getting the error:

> [2/2] QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 790: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'REGEXP'

I use `"beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "1.0.*"` in `composer.json`. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use it like `WHERE REGEXP(CONCAT(",", setcolumn, ","), ",(val1|val2|val3),") = 1`

Comment: Thanks. Here is my actual working condition `REGEXP(CONCAT(',', setColumn, ','), CONCAT(',(', comparedColumn, '),')) = 1`