# FIND_IN_SET with multiple value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to search multiple values from database field. below is my query.

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('12,13,15,15',category_id)
```

How i search its not working for me.

[image]

Comment: You need to swap your arguments for `FIND_IN_SET()`.

Comment: I would have been tempted to try that before posting

Comment: I think you should modify your query as `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE FIND_IN_SET('category_id','12,13,15,15')`

Comment: I was trying to solve a similar problem and stumbled upon this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015403/mysql-find-in-set-with-multiple-search-string gem of an answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`FIND_IN_SET()` can only be used to search for a single value in a comma-separated list, it doesn't work with two lists.

You'll need to call it separately for each value.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('12', category_id) OR FIND_IN_SET('13', category_id) OR FIND_IN_SET('15', category_id)
```

It would be better if you normalized your schema instead of using comma-separated lists. If you create a many-to-many table with the category IDs, you could do:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename AS t1
JOIN item_categories AS c ON t1.id = c.table_id
WHERE c.category_id IN (12, 13, 15)
```

Comment: I think this is the correct solution to this problem as we know find_in_set on searches only one value.

Answer (score 3):

FIND_IN_SET is not the solution.
Try to use REGEXP:

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` 
WHERE CONCAT(',', `category_id`, ',') REGEXP ',(12|13|15),';
```

But even if it's less pretty, it's better to use LIKE for performance reasons :

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` 
WHERE CONCAT(',', `category_id`, ',') LIKE '%,12,%' OR CONCAT(',', `category_id`, ',') LIKE '%,13,%' OR CONCAT(',', `category_id`, ',') LIKE '%,15,%';
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar need. To solve this I created a couple of stored functions:

The first one is all_in_set(a,b), and checks if all items in a are in b:

```
delimiter $$

drop function if exists all_in_set;

CREATE FUNCTION all_in_set(set1 varchar(1024),set2 varchar(1024)) RETURNS boolean
    NO SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'verify if all of the items in set1 are in set2'

BEGIN


declare i int default 0;
declare c varchar(128);
declare campos1 int;


set campos1=length(set1) - length(replace(set1, ',', '')) + 1;
set i=1;



while i<=campos1 do
    set c=SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(set1, ',', i), ',', -1);
    if find_in_set(c,set2)=0 then
        return false;
    end if;
    set i=i+1;
end while;


return true;

END$$

delimiter ;
```

for testing you can use:

```
> select all_in_set('a,b,c','a,b,c,d,e,f'),all_in_set('a,x,c','a,b,c,d,e,f');
+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| all_in_set('a,b,c','a,b,c,d,e,f') | all_in_set('a,x,c','a,b,c,d,e,f') |
+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|                                 1 |                                 0 |
+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

The second ne is any_in_set(a,b) which returns true if at least one of the items in a is included in b.

```
delimiter $$

drop function if exists any_in_set;

CREATE FUNCTION any_in_set(set1 varchar(1024),set2 varchar(1024)) RETURNS boolean
    NO SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'verify if at least one of the items in set1 is in set 2'

BEGIN

declare i int default 0;
declare c varchar(128);
declare campos1 int;


set campos1=length(set1) - length(replace(set1, ',', '')) + 1;
set i=1;


while i<=campos1 do
    set c=SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(set1, ',', i), ',', -1);
    if find_in_set(c,set2)<>0 then
        return true;
    end if;
    set i=i+1;
end while;


return false;

END$$

delimiter ;
```

for testing you can use:

```
> select any_in_set('x,y,c','a,b,c,d,e,f'),any_in_set('x,y,z','a,b,c,d,e,f');
+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| any_in_set('x,y,c','a,b,c,d,e,f') | any_in_set('x,y,z','a,b,c,d,e,f') |
+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|                                 1 |                                 0 |
+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.018 sec)
```