# Is it possible to concatenate strings from data set items in find_in_set()?

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following query:

```
set @var = 'A,B,C';
select from tbl_one where find_in_set(col_x, @var);
```

However, I have another table, which has column values based on @var as follows:

```
id    col_a
1     my.A
2     my.B
3     my.C
```

What I would like to do, is to use the same @var, but concatenate items in data set with 'my.' to be able to perform select using `find_in_set(col_a, @var)` which will be analogous to

```
select * from table_two where col_a in ('my.A', 'my.B', 'my.C')
```

Is it possible and how to do it?

Comment: This will help you to some extent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015403/mysql-find-in-set-with-multiple-search-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can remove the substring `my.` to the `col_x` column, using [`Replace()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function, for comparison purpose. **Note** that it will not modify the original data.
- Now, you can utilize the `Find_in_set()` function to look for a match.

Try the following:

```
SET @var = 'A,B,C';
SELECT FROM tbl_two 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(REPLACE(col_x, 'my.', ''), @var);
```

---

If there is a chance that you may have `my.` substring in the middle/end of the `col_x` values as well, and we need to replace only from the beginning. We could use [`Trim()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function in that case:

```
SET @var = 'A,B,C';
SELECT FROM tbl_two 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(TRIM(LEADING 'my.' FROM col_x), @var);
```

Comment: `replace` works! thanks a lot. (`concat` you suggested before edit didn't work)

Comment: @AlexanderZhak yes I interpreted question incorrectly previously. Please check the updated answer. There is one more approach covering some edge cases.