# How to match comma seprated string with comma seprated value in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to select rows who have comma separated values with comma separated value in column.

Before i was using FIND_IN_SET(needle,source)  method to match single value.

Mysql table is like

```
id       data 
1        -a-,-b-,-c-
2        -f-,-g-,-h-
3        -a-,-b-,-h-
```

I want to get rows which have -c-,-p-,-h- in data column.

Comment: Fix your data model!!!  Don't store multiple values in a delimited string.  It is not the SQL way to store multiple values.  Use a junction/association table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL find\_in\_set with multiple search string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015403/mysql-find-in-set-with-multiple-search-string)

Comment: use `LIKE '%-c-%' ` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Gordon is correct. Strings of comma-separated values in SQL columns is the number one antipattern in database design. It takes all the optimizations and elegance of SQL and throws it in the trash. Fix it as soon as you can by adding another table.

In the meantime you could try

```
 SELECT whatever 
   FROM table
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET('-c-', data) > 0
    AND FIND_IN_SET('-p-', data) > 0
    AND FIND_IN_SET('-h-', data) > 0
```

That finds rows with all three tokens you mention, in any order.