# How to get result properly from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

This is my product table

[image]

and I want to get all product where product_sizes in (Xl, M)

I am trying into this code

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,`sell_price`,`product_sizes`,`product_colors`
FROM `view_product_listing` 
WHERE `product_sizes` in ('XL', 'M')
```

return to me productId 15 and 16 but I want to productId 4,14,15,16

Comment: Please stop here and re-think your approach of storing serialized/comma separated data into the db - This approach will lead to many many issues. This is not scalable, nor maintainable. As you see even a single SELECT can be a huge pain. Read over [database normalization](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)...

Comment: Related topic - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 2):

You should seriously avoid storing the sizes as CSV (comma separated) data, see below for an alternative table design.  As a workaround, we can use `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT id, name, sell_price, product_sizes, product_colors
FROM view_product_listing
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('M', product_sizes) > 0 OR FIND_IN_SET('XL', product_sizes) > 0;
```

But note that a much better database design would be to have a separate table for products, sizes, and colors: (colors omitted)

```
products
id | name                                 | sell_price |
4  | Women Maxi White Dress               | 550.00     |
14 | Women Maxi Blue Dress                | 700.00     |
15 | Women Fit and Flare Multicolor Dress | 750.00     |
16 | Floral Print Straight Kurta          | 699.00     |

sizes
product_id | product_size
4          | XL
4          | M
14         | XL
14         | XXL
14         | L
14         | M
15         | XL
16         | M
```

Now we can use a straightforward join to find all products, and their metadata, which have either the medium or XL size:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.name,
    p.sell_price,
    s.product_size
FROM products p
INNER JOIN sizes s
    ON p.id = s.product_id
WHERE
    s.product_size IN ('M', 'XL');
```

Comment: _a much better database design would be to have a separate table for products, sizes, and colors..._ +1

Comment: @B001ᛦ This is like the fourth CSV MySQL question I have seen in a few hours, and I got tired of just giving the workaround.  So, it is better to explain what the OP should be doing, I think :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-find_in_set/) like this,

**Version 1:**

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,`sell_price`,`product_sizes`,`product_colors`
FROM `view_product_listing` 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('XL',product_sizes) OR FIND_IN_SET('M',product_sizes)
```

**EDIT 1**

There is one more approach to achieve this,

**Version 2:**

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,`sell_price`,`product_sizes`,`product_colors`
FROM `view_product_listing` 
WHERE CONCAT(',',product_sizes,',') REGEXP ",(XL|M),"
```

Source link for second [version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26195280/6556397).

**EDIT 2**

You `product_sizes` is having spaces after commas, which is not the behaviour find_in_set is expecting. To trim all spaces from that column,

```
UPDATE `table` SET `product_sizes` = REPLACE(`product_sizes`, ' ', '')
```

And now run any version query you want to try, it will work.

Comment: it is working SELECT `id`,`name`,`sell_price`,`product_sizes`,`product_colors`
FROM `view_product_listing` 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('XL',product_sizes) OR FIND_IN_SET('M',product_sizes)

Comment: Okay, find_in_set splits a string into array so, XL,M is not exists in a string which splits into array.

Comment: why it's not working SELECT `id`,`name`,`sell_price`,`product_sizes`,`product_colors`
FROM `view_product_listing` 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('XL,M', product_sizes)

Comment: It's like `explode(',' $str)` followed by `in_array` like in PHP. So, core functionalities, its build that way, can't do much.

Comment: why not getting only 'M' using FIND_IN_SET("M",product_sizes) ?

Comment: OP, check my **EDIT 2** section of answer for your question!

Answer (score 1):

use find_in_set()

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,`sell_price`,`product_sizes`,`product_colors`
FROM `view_product_listing` 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(product_sizes,'XL,M')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only searching for one size you could use the built-in MySQL function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,`sell_price`,`product_sizes`,`product_colors`
FROM `view_product_listing` 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('XL', product_sizes)
```

However it only supports a single string (unless you add additional `OR`'s, but that quickly becomes tedious).

The best approach would be to restructure your database so that the product sizes of items are in a seperate table with a reference to the item table and a size table.

That way you don't have to update your queries whenever you want to introduce new sizes and it will improve performance for your query.

**A word of warning,**

Do not attempt a `LIKE` clause, because search for `LIKE '%XL%'` will also match `XXL`

Comment: But we could use `REGEXP` here, e.g. `WHERE product_sizes REGEXP '[[:<:]](XL|M)[[:>:]]'`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen True, but that has a serious impact on performance and also has to be updated whenever you want to introduce new sizes